# Problemas al editar Padres e Hijos con PHP y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, funciones, parametros

tengo un problema q no se como puedo resolver esto, intente crear un función diferente pero no creo q sea lo mejor ya q me hace una llamada innecesaria.

El problema es:

Tengo una funcion que se llama `modificarCuenta` y tiene como parámetro `idpuc`. que contiene el id de la fila de la tabla.

```
function modificarCuenta(idpuc)
```

cuando edito el padre todo funciona me deja editar y no ocurre nada
pero las filas tienen un botón que al dar click me muestra sus hijos.

Como pueden ver acá, el hijo tiene los primero 4 digitos del codigo del padre.

PD(El código no es el mismo que el ID)

PD2(Para encontrar el id de los hijos utilizo esto

```
let idCuentasplit = idpuc.split("_");
let idCuenta = idCuentasplit[1];
```

esto me sirve para separar el código y el id de ese hijo

Ejemplo: 1325_155
el primer dato es el codigo del padre (No es el id) el segundo dato es el id del hijo) asi que utilizo eso para separar y poder obtener el id del hijo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego paso idpuc e idcuenta a php asi

```
 var parametros = {accion: MODIFICAR_DESCRIPCION_NIIF, idpuc: idpuc, idCuenta: idCuenta}
```

Ya estando en PHP llamo a idcuenta e idpuc

```
    $idpuc = $this->getString("idpuc");
    $idCuenta = $this->getString("idCuenta");
```

y con los id puedo editar el dato

```
    $PUCeditar = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idpuc);
```

La cosa es q al tener el codigo asi solo me deja editar el padre mas no el hijo

PD3(esto es lo q me pasa a php al editar padre: idpuc: 153 y esto es lo q me trae al querer editar el hijo idpuc: 1325_155
idCuenta: 155)

Como pueden ver en realidad solo necesito el idCuenta pera editar el hijo

```
$PUCeditar = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idCuenta);
```

Asi ya me deja editar el hijo pero no el padre asi q intente agregar ambos

```
    $PUCeditar = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idpuc);
    $PUCeditarHijos = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idCuenta);
```

Asi pero ahi no me funciona ninguno.

```
    var_dump($idpuc);
    var_dump($idCuenta);
    
    $PUCeditar = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idpuc);

    $PUCeditarHijos = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idCuenta);
    exit;
```

hice varios var_Dumps y esto es lo q me trae

al editar el padre

```
string(3) "147" string(0) ""
```

y un error

> "No existe el PUC con identificador array (\n  0 => 0,\n)"

y al editar el hijo

```
string(8) "1325_155" string(3) "155"
```

y el error

> "No existe el PUC con identificador array (\n  0 => 1325,\n)"

CLaro entiendo por  q ocurre ese error pero no se como puedo solucionar eso. y cual sea la mejor forma.

En general todo me funciona pero no se como puedo arreglar esa parte

PD5(Si me falto me avisan y lo edito, gracias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo logre solucionar lo que hice fue en esta parte

```
$PUCeditar = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idpuc);
$PUCeditarHijos = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idCuenta);
```

agregar un if-elseif

```
    if ($idCuenta === 0) {
        $PUCeditar = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idpuc);
    } elseif (is_int($idCuenta)) {
        $PUCeditarHijos = PlanUnicoCuenta::crear($idCuenta);
    }
```

y esto al principio

```
    $PUCeditar = null;
    $PUCeditarHijos = null;
```

y ya